# How to set to view on Spark UI after completed App

Tags: apache-spark

I've tried to set to view on Spark UI after completed App.

I referenced https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html but I don't know how to set Spark cluster in detail.

I have a four computer: one is master cluster, the rest is slave cluster.

It is written on this page to enter these commands.

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs
```

Do these only need to be entered on the master cluster? Or do I have to fill in all the clusters?

I tried both in spark-defaults.conf, but I got the same error When I run spark app.

```
failed on connection exception:java.net.ConnectException: Connection 
refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to configure history server ?

Comment: Are you talking about starting a server like `./sbin/start-history-server.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web UI after the application has finished by persisting events using EventLoggingListener and using Spark History Server.

Use Spark History Server to view the event logs in a browser.

Enable `INFO` logging level for `org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener` logger to see what happens inside `EventLoggingListener`.

Add the following line to `conf/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener=INFO
```

You can start History Server by executing `start-history-server.sh` shell script and stop it using `stop-history-server.sh`

Comment: When I started `start-history-server.sh`. I got a error `failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer:
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:75)
        ... 6 more
`